# Instagram iPhone hook - photo isn't exported

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, instagram

Could you tell my, what I did wrong, that the photo isn't displayed in new Instagram? It isn't exported there at all.

EDIT: I see problem is that it isn't shown in Preview of Instagram. WHen I go "Next", there is visible a thumbnail. My output picture is 1000x1000 if it matters.

```
NSString *savePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Image.igo"];

// Write image to PNG
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(preview.image, 1.0) writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];

NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://app"];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) 
{
    //imageToUpload is a file path with .ig file extension
    documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:savePath]];

    documentInteractionController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
    documentInteractionController.delegate = self;

    documentInteractionController.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"bla bla bla" forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];
    [documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

http://help.instagram.com/customer/portal/articles/884829-images-doesn-t-display-when-importing-from-3rd-party-app-ios-only-

Here's an official info from Instagram.